# Unwanted application of CSS variables when SvelteKit prefetches links

Tags: tailwind-css, sveltekit

I'm using tailwindcss for styling.

I want to have dynamic control over the horizontal padding/margin of my pages.
Currently I'm using a CSS variable that's being set in the global stylesheet. This value is the default, and is overwritten by child layouts.

The reason I use a CSS variable is so I can set the horizontal padding/margin of the navbar as well.

./app.css

```css
:root {
  --page-px: 6rem;
}
```

In the top-most __layout.svelte there is the following code.

./routes/__layout.svelte

```html
<main class="px-[var(--page-px)]">
  <slot />
</main>
```

...and in a __layout.svelte further down the file structure, there is this code.

./routes/my-account/__layout.svelte

```html
<slot />

<style>
  :root {
    --page-px: 12rem;
  }
</style>
```

Now, the problem is that if I use the `sveltekit:prefetch` attribute to prefetch links before I click them. Then the styles are loaded before I even get to click.

That is, when I hover (without clicking) a prefetching link, the current page shifts and gets narrower, as the child layout's styling is applied.

Is there a way around this behavior?

Comment: I am not familiar with Svelte, but when the route actually changes, do any classes change above <main>? If so you could use a different specificity for the variable rather than just root.